# Receive Json API response and send Json Response with Golang

Tags: json, api, go

I am trying to build a simple Web Application in which , when we go to url `http://localhost:8888/`, it should call an API endpoint(which contains JSON Response) and select only a particular key element in that JSON and send that particular key element as a response in JSON format.

**GO code :**
I am trying this

```
func viewdags(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    response, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/admin/rest_api/api?api=list_dags") //API endpoint
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Printf("HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    } else {
         //logic goes here


func main(){
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/",viewdags)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8888",router)
```

This is the result JSON when `func viewdags(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` is called.

```
{
"airflow_cmd":"airflow list_dags",
"arguments":{
"api":"list_dags"},
"call_time":"Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:13:20 GMT",
"http_response_code":200,
"output":{
"stderr":"",
"stdin":"",
"stdout":"\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\nDAGS\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\nairflow_sample\ndag_today\nexample_bash_operator\nexample_branch_dop_operator_v3\nexample_branch_operator\nexample_http_operator\nexample_passing_params_via_test_command\nexample_pig_operator\nexample_python_operator\nexample_short_circuit_operator\nexample_skip_dag\nexample_subdag_operator\nexample_subdag_operator.section-1\nexample_subdag_operator.section-2\nexample_trigger_controller_dag\nexample_trigger_target_dag\nexample_xcom\nlatest_only\nlatest_only_with_trigger\nmy_custom_dag\nsample_dag\nsample_dag1\ntest_utils\ntutorial\n\n"},
"post_arguments":{},
"response_time":"Tue, 21 Jan 2020 15:00:00 GMT",
"status":"OK"
}
```

So, I want to take only the `stdout` which is inside `output` and pass it as response in JSON Format.
That is, the JSON response should be :

```
{
"stdout":"\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\nDAGS\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\nairflow_sample\ndag_today\nexample_bash_operator\nexample_branch_dop_operator_v3\nexample_branch_operator\nexample_http_operator\nexample_passing_params_via_test_command\nexample_pig_operator\nexample_python_operator\nexample_short_circuit_operator\nexample_skip_dag\nexample_subdag_operator\nexample_subdag_operator.section-1\nexample_subdag_operator.section-2\nexample_trigger_controller_dag\nexample_trigger_target_dag\nexample_xcom\nlatest_only\nlatest_only_with_trigger\nmy_custom_dag\nsample_dag\nsample_dag1\ntest_utils\ntutorial\n\n"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problem(s) did you run into in your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's legit to unmarshal a complex JSON into a simple Go struct having only the fields you want. Other fields from the input stream will be ignored.

In [this playground code](https://play.golang.org/p/93zwiPIzarr) (adapted from [this sample](https://www.programming-idioms.org/idiom/91/load-json-file-into-struct/2463/go)), the JSON input

```
        {
            "FirstName":"Napoléon",
            "Age": 51,
            "Other": null,
            "unrelated": 42,
            "Things": "foobar"
        }
```

is turned into this simpler Go object having 2 fields:

```
{Napoléon 51}
```

One thing to be careful about though is that your input field name `sdtout` is lowercase, but your Go struct field needs to be capitalized `Stdout`. Thus your type def will look like

```
type MyInput struct {
    Stdout string `json:"stdout"`
}
```